# Multiple Lines Webrequest From RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net

Ok so i'm trying to make multiple webrequests, but in a different way.

i'm trying to let my users add the websites on each line of a richtextbox and when they click a button it will run this:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("Website")
```

But not for the hole richtextbox, but for every line, so say the richtextbox has all these lines:

```
google.com
facebook.com
youtube.com
```

and once they click the button, those sites will be put into the space where it says Website.

If anyone can help me with this, thank you!

Also sorry if this is messy, I don't think there's any other way to present this information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could get you started. Textboxes have a `Lines` property that contains a collection of strings from each line of the textbox ([See this MSDN page for reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx)

```
    Dim arrUrls() As String = RichTextBox1.Lines
    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(arrUrls)
         If Not arrUrls(i).Length=0 Then Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(arrUrls(i))
    Next
```

Comment: The arrUrls array has each of the lines from the richtextbox in it as strings - and in your case, each of these strings in the array is a website URL. Once you have that, you can do whatever you want with the URLs. I edited my answer to account for any blank lines - I've tested it and it's working fine. Is there anything else going on?

Comment: i'm not trying to get the websites form every line, like i want it to be able to detect the if the websites are on different lines of te richtextbox, but not in the lines format, and then it takes them from each line, and goes to them...